# search for exact pattern using sed and print in new line

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I've a large file with data like

```
cd24511   |cd25512|cd24541|cd11554            0| cd24512      |cd24542|cd24531            0| cd24513      |cd24543        0| cd27531      |cd27531|cd27541            2740| cd27521   |cd27541            2261|
```

I want to format it using sed in the below way.

```
cd24511  |cd25512|cd24541|cd11554  0|

cd24512  |cd24542|cd24531          0|

cd24513  |cd24543                  0|

cd27531  |cd27531|cd27541          2740|

cd27521  |cd27541                  2261|
```

If I search number pattern using sed it is listing me all numbers like below

```
245112551224541115540245122454224531024513245430
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach:

```
$ sed -r 's/\s+[0-9]+\s*\|/&\n/g' file | column -t 
cd24511  |cd25512|cd24541|cd11554  0|
cd24512  |cd24542|cd24531          0|
cd24513  |cd24543                  0|
cd27531  |cd27531|cd27541          2740|
cd27521  |cd27541                  2261|
```

Not sure if you really want the empty lines or not but you could do:

```
$ sed -r 's/\s+[0-9]+\s*\|/&\n/g' file | column -t | sed 's/$/\n/'      
cd24511  |cd25512|cd24541|cd11554  0|

cd24512  |cd24542|cd24531          0|

cd24513  |cd24543                  0|

cd27531  |cd27531|cd27541          2740|

cd27521  |cd27541                  2261|
```

---

#### Explanation:

Breaking down the first `sed` script:

```
s        # substitution command 

/        # start of regular expression match 

\s+      # one or more whitespace characters
[0-9]+   # one or more digits
\s*      # zero or more whitespace characters
\|       # literal | character 
/        # end of regular expression match, start of replacement

&\n      # & contains the match, add the newline character 

/        # end of replacement, start of flags

g        # global flag
```

The `column -t` command handles the tabular layout for us and the double spacings replaces the end of each line `$` with a newline character `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` solution.

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/^[0-9]+\|/) $i=$i"\n"}1' file | column -t
cd24511  |cd25512|cd24541|cd11554  0|
cd24512  |cd24542|cd24531          0|
cd24513  |cd24543                  0|
cd27531  |cd27531|cd27541          2740|
cd27521  |cd27541                  2261|
```

It test all fields, and if it contains only number and a `|` add newline.